# pandas changed column value condition of three other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'pred': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'a': [0.4, 0.6, 0.35, 0.5],
                   'b': [0.2, 0.4, 0.32, 0.1],
                   'c': [0.1, 0, 0.2, 0.2],
                   'd': [0.3, 0, 0.1, 0.2]})
```

I want to change values on 'pred' column, based on columns a,b,c,d , as following:

**if** a has the value at column a is larger than the values of column b,c,d
and
**if** one of columns - b , c or d has value larger than 0.25

then change value in 'pred' to 0. so the results should be:

```
    pred    a       b         c      d
0   1        0.4    0.2      0.1    0.1
1   0        0.6    0.4      0.0    0.0
2   0        0.35   0.32      0.2   0.3
3   4        0.5    0.1      0.2    0.2
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a boolean condition/mask then use `loc` to set value to `0` where condition is `True`

```
cols = ['b', 'c', 'd']
mask = df[cols].lt(df['a'], axis=0).all(1) & df[cols].gt(.25).any(1)
df.loc[mask, 'pred'] = 0
```

---

```
   pred     a     b    c    d
0     1  0.40  0.20  0.1  0.1
1     0  0.60  0.40  0.0  0.0
2     0  0.35  0.32  0.2  0.3
3     4  0.50  0.10  0.2  0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

def row_cond(row):
    m_val = max(row[2:])
    if row[1]>m_val and m_val>0.25:
        row[0] = 0
    return row

df = pd.DataFrame({'pred': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'a': [0.4, 0.6, 0.35, 0.5],
                   'b': [0.2, 0.4, 0.32, 0.1],
                   'c': [0.1, 0, 0.2, 0.2],
                   'd': [0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.2]})

new_df = df.apply(row_cond,axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    pred    a       b       c       d
0   1.0     0.40    0.20    0.1     0.1
1   0.0     0.60    0.40    0.0     0.0
2   0.0     0.35    0.32    0.2     0.3
3   4.0     0.50    0.10    0.2     0.2
```